# Styling only text in <a> and ignoring <img>

Tags: html, css, image

I have a style like:

```
a {border-bottom: 1px solid gray; text-decoration: none}
```

Now if I put an `<img>` inside a `<a>`, the `<img>` gets the border too. Is there a way to prevent this?

`a img {border:0}` doesn't work because `a` has the border, not `img`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wp480vdv/1/

Adding classes to either have a border or not is difficult for large sites.

Comment: can't you add a class to the anchor, and add a style so the border isn't added? eg. `a.noborder { border: 0; }`

Comment: That'll very difficult for large sites.

Comment: So you dont want border on `a` that has `img` as child?

Comment: @Elmo May I ask if you downvoted my answer as it use classes?

Comment: @LGSon No I didn't. Don't take downvotes too seriously, they can have random reasons like the mood of a person.

Comment: I don't, been here too long for that, just ran into a few OP that changed question and then down voted as answer became kind of wrong based on specs.

Comment: Writing _Adding classes to either have a border or not is difficult for large sites._ surprises me a little, as it is when you do have big sites classes matters more, so why do you want to skip that in favor of script, which will be the only choice in your case as there is no parent selector to use? ... well, you can of course use the `href` attribute to target anchors with a specific url but that would probably be more difficult to maintain than classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JQuery to do this

**Solution 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/wp480vdv/8/

```
$('a').has('img').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

**Solution 2** http://jsfiddle.net/wp480vdv/9/

```
$("a:not(:has(>img))").css('border-bottom', '1px solid gray');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to give underline for text not for image, then you don't need to give border-bottom for `<a>` tag.
You can modify your html like that.

html

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <span>hello</span>
    <img src="a.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Here by default in `<a>` tag, there is underline.
So if use `a{text-decoration:none;}` so why you want to give border-bottom.
Anyway if want to give border-bottom for text then you can do like that.

css

```css
a {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid gray;*/
  text-decoration: none
}

span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

img {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A selection based on the content is not supported in CSS; and i doubt it will always be.
The nearer thing you can do, without Javascript is the attribute selector:

```
a {border-bottom: 1px solid gray; text-decoration: none}
a[href="/foo"] {border:0px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wp480vdv/10/

Might it be something in the attribute of the `<a>` that contains image different from the `<a>` containing only text?